# Select data from another table from JPA repository

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, mariadb, jpa-2.0

I have this query in JPA repository:

```
@Repository
public interface PaymentTransactionsDailyFactsRepository extends JpaRepository<PaymentTransactionsDailyFacts, Integer> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT " + 
            " COUNT(*) count, " + 
            " SUM(amount) volume, " + 
            " DATE(created_at) date, " + 
            " YEAR(created_at) year, " + 
            " MONTH(created_at) month, " + 
            " WEEK(created_at) week, " + 
            " DAY(created_at) day, " + 
            " type transaction_type, " + 
            " contract_id, merchant_id, terminal_id, " + 
            " status, card_brand, currency " + 
            " FROM payment_transactions " + 
            " WHERE status NOT IN ('pending_async','pending','pending_review','in_progress','new') AND created_at BETWEEN :start_date AND :end_date " + 
            " GROUP by date, contract_id, merchant_id, terminal_id, transaction_type, status, card_brand, currency", nativeQuery = true)
    List<PaymentTransactionsDailyFacts> generateDailyFacts(@Param("start_date") LocalDate start_date, @Param("end_date") LocalDate end_date);
}
```

But when I execute it in Spring Scheduler I get error:

```
SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: No such column: id
```

When I execute this query in MariaDB it's working fine:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) count,  SUM(amount) volume,  DATE(created_at) date,  YEAR(created_at) year,  MONTH(created_at) month,  WEEK(created_at) week,  DAY(created_at) day,  type transaction_type,  contract_id, merchant_id, terminal_id,  status, card_brand, currency  FROM payment_transactions  WHERE status NOT IN ('pending_async','pending','pending_review','in_progress','new') AND created_at BETWEEN '2011-04-11 00:00:01' AND '2029-04-11 00:00:00'  GROUP by date, contract_id, merchant_id, terminal_id, transaction_type, status, card_brand, currency
```

As you can see I'm running this native query for table `payment_transactions` but I'm expecting a result for table `payment_transactions_daily_facts`. Is there a way to implement this query properly?

Comment: Is there a `id` column in the database table `payment_transactions`. When you excute the query in mariadb directly it shows you the result set because you are not asking for `id` column to return. However, in your spring-data application, it should build `PaymentTransactionsDailyFacts` entities which seem to have property named `id`. If you publish the entity definition and table definition, we will be able to check whats wrong there.

Comment: And your `PaymentTransactionsDailyFacts` has an Id as well I guess. If that's the case you need to get an Id from your native script as well

Comment: Btw me having to ask that is a sign for bad explanation on your part. It should be clear that the code of your `PaymentTransactionsDailyFacts` will be needed to solve your issue.

Comment: Maybe you can share your `PaymentTransactionsDailyFacts` Entity

Comment: https://pastebin.com/u5TdVX32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get all `PaymentTransactionsDailyFacts` entities which are between given `start_date` and `end_date` and their `status` is not one of ('pending_async','pending','pending_review','in_progress','new'), you can use the following query.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * " 
            " FROM payment_transactions " + 
            " WHERE status NOT IN ('pending_async','pending','pending_review','in_progress','new') AND created_at BETWEEN :start_date AND :end_date " + 
            " GROUP by date, contract_id, merchant_id, terminal_id, transaction_type, status, card_brand, currency", nativeQuery = true)
```

But, since you have used `group by` in your query, it seems you are trying to get some aggregate data, not just a list of `PaymentTransactionsDailyFacts` entities which satisfy the conditions. 
If that is the case, you are doing it all wrong. You have to use **projections**.

Here is a quick tutorial on how to use spring data projections. 
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections

OR. you can read the official documentation here.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections

## UPDATE : Using Projections

1. First create an interface like below somewhere in the project. You should adjust the return types as needed.

   ```
   public interface PtdsDTO {
       Integer getCount();
       BigDecimal getVolume();
       LocalDate getDate();
       Short getYear();
       Short getMonth();
       Short getWeek();
       Short getDay();
       String getTransactionType();
       Integer getContactId();
       Integer getMerchantId();
       Integer getTerminalId();
       String getStatus();
       String getCardBrand();
       String getCurrency();
   }
   ```
2. Then, import that interface at the top of the respective repository.
3. Change the return type of your repository to `List<PtdsDTO>`.

   ```
   List<PtdsDTO> generateDailyFacts(@Param("start_date") LocalDate start_date, @Param("end_date") LocalDate end_date);
   ```

Thats it.

Comment: Can you show me code example with projections, please

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `id` in Query

```
@Query(value = "SELECT " + 
            " id," + 
            " COUNT(*) count, " + 
            " SUM(amount) volume, " + 
            " DATE(created_at) date, " + 
            " YEAR(created_at) year, " + 
            " MONTH(created_at) month, " + 
            " WEEK(created_at) week, " + 
            " DAY(created_at) day, " + 
            " type transaction_type, " + 
            " contract_id, merchant_id, terminal_id, " + 
            " status, card_brand, currency " + 
            " FROM payment_transactions " + 
            " WHERE status NOT IN ('pending_async','pending','pending_review','in_progress','new') AND created_at BETWEEN :start_date AND :end_date " + 
            " GROUP by date, contract_id, merchant_id, terminal_id, transaction_type, status, card_brand, currency", nativeQuery = true)
    List<PaymentTransactionsDailyFacts> generateDailyFacts(@Param("start_date") LocalDate start_date, @Param("end_date") LocalDate end_date);
```